# how to show a popup alert window in background in flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, firebase-cloud-messaging, system-alert-window

here I'm developing a chat application using AWS and flutter, i want to show a popup alert like a true Caller, I did it using a #system_alert_window it works perfectly when app is opened and AWS connect connected. but i also want it to show When the app in INACTIVE STATE or Terminated state.

What I did was When a Msg received from the AWS socket i show a popup alert in using **system_alert_window** but the problem is in Background ideal state AWS Socket got disconnected and **system_alert_window** was Not triggered.
here i want to keep the **AWS socket** connected or Some Other ways to Trigger the **system_alert_window**
is there a way to Trigger it using Push notification
Here im using **FCM(Firebase cloud messaging)**

Comment: You can use notifications to open the pop-up

Comment: Try executing your system_window code when you receive notifications and place your code inside FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage()